# ReactJS: routing configuration issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and doing some sample applications.
I am looking the concepts on "**react-router**" and gone through one example.

## AppHeader.jsx

```
 import React from 'react';
 import Router from 'react-router';  
 import { Link, Route, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

 class AppHeader extends React.Component{

  render(){
      return (
            <div>
                <div className="header">
                        <ul>
                        <li><Link to="home">Home</Link></li>    
                        <li><Link to="fundamentals">React-Fundamentals</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="components">React-Components</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="flux">React-Flux</Link></li>
                            <li><Link to="babel">React-Babel</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="crede-menu">
                                <li><Link to="register">Register</Link></li>
                                <li><Link to="login">Login</Link></li>
                        </div>
                       </div>

                          <center>
                              <RouteHandler></RouteHandler>
                          </center>

                          <div className="footer">
                          <p><center>!copy rights reserved @ 2016</center></p>
                 </div>
            </div>
      )
    }

 }
 export default AppHeader;
```

## app.js

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import Router from 'react-router/lib/Router';
 import browserHistory from 'react-router/lib/browserHistory';
 import Link from 'react-router/lib/Link';
 import Route from 'react-router/lib/Route';
 import AppHeader from '../jsx/header.jsx';
 import Home from '../jsx/home.jsx';
 import Fundamentals from '../jsx/fundamentals.jsx';
 import Components from '../jsx/components.jsx';
 import Flux from '../jsx/flux.jsx';
 import Babel from '../jsx/babel.jsx';
 import Register from '../jsx/register.jsx';
 import Login from '../jsx/login.jsx';
 var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
 var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;


 var routes = (
     <Route component={AppHeader}>
       <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="fundamentals" component={Fundamentals}/> 
        <Route path="components" component={Components}/>
        <Route path="flux" component={Flux}/>
        <Route path="babel" component={Babel}/>
     </Route>
   );

 /*running the routes*/
  ReactDOM.render(<Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />, document.getElementById('reactApp'))
```

please help me anything wrong here.when i run my example i am getting error as below.

```
 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `AppHeader`.
```

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `AppHeader`.
[image: folder structure]

Comment: your path 
 `import AppHeader from '../jsx/header.jsx';` is wrong

Comment: i renamed and changed to '../jsx/AppHeader.jsx', still same error
please help that would be great for me to proceed further.

Comment: what is your project structure? Upload a screenshots of the files or something

Comment: ok sure will upload screenshot

Comment: where is your app.js in the screenshot? in which dir?

Comment: i just changed app.js to routing/routing.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134359/discussion-between-vallepu-veerendra-kumar-and-leo).

Comment: If you already imported Ruter from AppHeader.jsx, why doing it twice?

Comment: oh ok, i will remove and let you know

Comment: if i remove Router here, i am getting Router is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;

var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>Welcome !</div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Router>  
), document.getElementById('root'));
```